# BigDecimal with JPA and flexible scale

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have to map a `BigDecimal` in JPA:

```
@Column(name = "price", precision = 16, scale = 4)
private BigDecimal price;
```

The precision and scale is also set up in the database correctly.

However, with the given scale, all values are stored with a scale of 4 even the value does only need a scale of 2. And if, for example, I use a number like:

```
12.12345678
```

then this value is truncated to

```
12.1234
```

even the precision would allow a higher scale of 4 (because the allowed precision is 16 and the used precision is 6, hence Hibernate could store 10 digits more and use these digits even for the needed higher scale).

Is there any way that hibernate adapts the scale in dependent of the actual scale and its precision instead of having hard coded scale? If I map the BigDecimal with no scale:

```
@Column(name = "price", precision = 16)
private BigDecimal price;
```

then Hibernate defaults to 2. Is there something like a *flexible scale* in dependend of the maximum available `precision` in JPA? Because internally, BigDecimal does exactly something like that: If no scale is given (which is the default), then java adapts the needed scale in accordance to the available precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want something like `@PrePersist @PreUpdate` annotations to fix your `BigDecimal` scale before saving your entity.

Something like:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
    public void pricePrecisionConvertion() {
        // convert your bigdecimal scale to 2 here
        this.price.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
```

Setting `@Column` to a flexible scale to JPA (which I think it's not possible), your database could need be flexible as well, and I don't think databases in general have this option.