# How to define BigDecimal rounding strategy for BigDecimal in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, bigdecimal

I'm trying to persist payment amount field as Big Decimal via Spring Data JPA (Hibernate). I have define column like this:

@Column(precision = 19, scale = 3)

but the problem I'm facing is that the the UP strategy is being used when rounding the number while persisting. For example, if i try to persist 0.12345 it will save 0.124.

I need the DOWN rounding strategy in this situation and i don't know how to set this. I can probably set the scale and rounding strategy for my big decimal in constructor/setters but that doesn't seem like good option to me. Is there some annotation or argument which i need to pass to my jpa so it uses the down strategy while rounding?

Answer (score 1):

You can look here [BigDecimal with JPA and flexible scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171274/bigdecimal-with-jpa-and-flexible-scale) for some solution approach. I don't think it can be controlled with some property. I would say it's also not something that belongs on the domain layer, as it's a "business logic" to define how the prices are rounded.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is your business requirement, and it's ok to make this rounding in service, for example. The same as if you do a plain insert via sql, you'll have to make rounding yourself.

It's absolutely fine to have it in setter, like:

```java
public void setNumber(BigDecimal number) {
        this.number = number.setScale(SCALE, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    }
```